# How to query rows of multiple Google Sheets in chronological order of their entry?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want to query data of multiple sheets in the chronological order in which data is being entered in the sheet.

Comment: Data 1 sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vIMYCHnj-jS_bIzfenLWcBTLdLiIJJ576p-0nk9tvto/edit?usp=drivesdk
Data 2 sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEaMB75MASF5vuIjWcsRN7UjZrbg2la74Y6MbW1jBbA/edit?usp=drivesdk
RESULT REQUIRED SHEET
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Zl_mSbE7MHL9JX4XScfSch3wGLGh4AMT4Y-bbDGxH4/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: sheets are private

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(
 {IMPORTRANGE("1vIMYCHnj-jS_bIzfenLWcBTLdLiIJJ576p-0nk9tvto", "Sheet1!A1:C");
  IMPORTRANGE("1UEaMB75MASF5vuIjWcsRN7UjZrbg2la74Y6MbW1jBbA", "Sheet1!A2:C")},
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col3", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

for timestamp you need this script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
      nextCell.setValue(newDate);
   }
}
```

---

### how to add a script to your spreadsheet

- go to **Tools**
- select **Script editor**

  [image: 0]
- copy paste the script
- save the project under some name

  [image]
- click on run icon and authorise it...

  [image]
- select your account

  [image]
- click on **Advanced**

  [image]
- select **Go to * (unsafe)**

  [image]
- click on **Allow** and return to your sheet (you can close script window/tab)

  [image]

Comment: Thats great!  But how do I add a time stamp?  The now function is dynamic and it changes to the latest time automatically.

Comment: @SurajS for timestamp you need a script - answer updated

Comment: Thank you ! But will this work even if I add new sheets ?